# Question about if structure and loops

Tags: shell-script, for, text-formatting

I am new in programing with bash script. Here is my problem: I am going to open a sort of data whose file name includes the date (format: `file_yyyymmddhh.nc`). There are some requirements:

- `mm` is from 01 to 12. This must be a two-digit integer.
- `dd` is from 01 to 28, 30, or 31, depending on the what month it is.

I tried to solve the problem with if structure and loops. I know that I could use something like this so that I can apply `${dd}` to my filename.

```
if [${mm} == 01] ; then 
  for ((i=1; i<=31; i=i+1))
  do 
    ${dd}=i
done
fi
```

But I don't know how to specify `${dd}` to be a 2-digit integer especially when `${dd} <= 9`. Is there any way to fix the code above?

Comment: @arzyfex I am going to open a list of files and the file name is formatted as 'yyyymmdd'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `printf` to format your numbers. Here the `%02d` denotes a two digit integer with leading zeros if appropriate.

```
dd=$(printf "%02d" $i)
```

You can extend this so that if `$y`, `$m`, `$d`, and `$h` contain your year, month, day, and hour numbers the construct could become this

```
file=$(printf "file_%04d%02d%02d%02d.nc" $y $m $d $h)
```

While we're here, your construct `${dd}=i` is incorrect. The `$` symbol is prefixed in front of a variable name to get that variable's value (in your case, `i` is the variable and `$i` equates to its value). So in your case you would instead have written `dd=$i`.

Comment: It works! And thanks for pointing out what I did wrong:)